# VS 2010 Unable to remove inherited additional dependencies

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Hi by mistake I added cv210d.lib, cxcore210d.lib and highgui210d.lib as inherited values under the project configuration->Linker->input->Additional Dependencies settings.

But I cannot seem to remove them from the "inherited" additional dependencies. So each time I start a new project I get an error because these liberties cannot be found.

There is an option to ignore the inherited dependencies but I cannot do this as it contains values I do need.

So I am looking for a way to remove these unwanted values from the "inherited" additional dependencies.

Comment: View + (Other Windows) + Property Manager.  Find out what property sheet you accidentally modified from that.

Comment: As Hans stated, you probably inadvertently modified a property sheet in the property manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was suggested I modified the property sheet in the property manager.

The reason I found it confusing though was that in the Property Manager view, there are three different ways to change the properties. Through clicking on the debug, release property sheets or the project properties . But when I opened each one I thought I was opening the same thing, as they look similar.

But the case is that, the properties from the debug and release property sheets are inherited to the project properties. And you cannot modify the inherited properties from the project properties.

Answer (score 9):

You can find the file "Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user" on your system and manually edit it as you want. Normally the file will be located at "C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\v4.0" location. It is an xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you accidentally add it to "Linker > Input" under "Property Manager > AnyProject > AnyConfiguration > Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user"?

Despite its strange position, this is the setting for all projects of the current user.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you put a wrong .lib file into Additional Dependencies it went to the inherited directory. You need to untick "Inherit from parent or project defaults". Then, to save inherited .lib files (such kernel.lib and etc.) you need to copy and paste all of them into the Additional Dependencies directory. So your computer cannot take the wrong .lib file and will use only Additional Dependencies which you wrote

Answer (score 0):

You can open with notepad the .vcxproj file of your project and find the lib you want to remove. Then, Delete that library from the xml field.