# Visual Studio 2010 Additional Dependencies

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, dependencies

I'm having more or less [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714269/vs-2010-unable-to-remove-inherited-additional-dependencies) problem, only I accidentally added a .dll file to the additional dependencies field just before the `;%(AdditionalDependencies)` and then removed it afterwards.

The problem is that even though I actually removed it from the exact same properties I added it (and have been searching frantically for it in any and all other possible places too,) it still shows up if I right-click the field and click "Edit" and keeps causing my compilations to fail even after I have wiped the project from my drive and checked out a new clean version.

Can anyone please help me or is this a bug with VS?

Comment: Please don't open so similar and localized questions.

Answer (score 0):

Close the solution, then delete *.suo and *.YourUserName.* files from the solution folder.

Or [If this is Microsoft team foundation source control]:

after fetting the latest version, checkout the whole solution folder for edit, or make sure that the solution is bound to source control (for automatic checkout-for-edit support)