# OpenCV error LNK1104: cannot open file 'opencv_core231.lib'

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013

Hi i have a problem running the OpenCV application using Visual Studio 2013 and Windows 8.1 x64.

I followed this guide: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cgo0UitHfp8
I did everything as said in the guide except the changes:
x64 instead of x86 and vs11 instead of vs10 in file paths.

Im trying to run it on OpenCV 2.4.6 (where file names are like 'opencv_core246.lib' and not 'opencv_core231.lib' like in the error.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you are including and linking the correct directories. This can be done in Visual Studio solution properties (right click on the solution and select `Properties`). For example (this is in Visual Studio 2010, but it should be similar in Visual Studio 2013)..

Set include path

[image: set include path, step 1]
[image: set include path, step 2]

Set library path

[image: set library path, step 1]
[image: set library path, step 2]

Set library dependencies

[image: set library dependencies, step 1]
[image: set library dependencies, step 2]

Comment: There is no install folder in my directory. I connected other folders instead. It still doesnt work. Why does it refer to the 2.3.1 file if I have installed 2.4.6? Maybe these are some "remains" from the previous installation attempt I have made using the tutorial from the official OpenCV website?

Comment: You connected other folders... what over folders? You need to include and link directories where your built version of OpenCV is.

Comment: I added the following: C:\opencv246\build\include\opencv and C:\opencv246\build\x64\vc11\lib I think these should already be added because I followed the instructional video.

Comment: yes these look correct. did you set library dependencies (it's the last step in my example above), this is where you list which .lib files you are linking? For example, if your project will be compiled in release configuration, you should link `opencv_core246.lib` among other `.lib` files, or if you are building in debug configuration then link `opencv_core246d.lib` file.

Comment: opencv_core231.lib is an inherited value set in Linker/Input window. I hope this can help.

Comment: ok, then you should remove project property files from which this was inherited. or just create and new project and set all the dependencies from scratch.

Comment: project properties can be set in properties pages, which you can see in View -> Property Manager.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z15yzzew.aspx

Comment: Everytime I create a new project these files are inherited (when I add the new project properties): opencv_core231.lib;opencv_imgproc231.lib;opencv_highgui231.lib;opencv_ml231.lib;opencv_video231.lib;opencv_features2d231.lib;opencv_calib3d231.lib;opencv_objdetect231.lib;opencv_contrib231.lib;opencv_legacy231.lib;opencv_flann231.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714269/vs-2010-unable-to-remove-inherited-additional-dependencies

Comment: This file contains only the following lines: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets">
  </ImportGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup />
  <ItemDefinitionGroup />
  <ItemGroup />
</Project>
 Nothing familiar to me

Comment: what file are you talking about?

Comment: see other answers and suggestions on that page. I don't think that editing `.user` file is the way to go. Look for the solution, now that you know what the problem is.

Comment: Now Im having different errors. I see it as a progress :) Here they are [link](http://sdrv.ms/1dtDdVN)

Comment: OK I fixed the problem. You have to link to x86 directories on x64 system.

Comment: If you want to compile your project as 64 bit. you need to set your target platform to x64 and link to 64 bit libraries. You can also set target to 32 bit (x86) and link to x86 lib files, but why do that?

Comment: I targetted the compilation to 64 bit and 32 bit. The problems i described below (2nd answer) still occur. I also replaced the DLL file with one downloaded from the internet but the error still appears. I really need to get OCV up and running.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was solved partially. Linking x86 libraries instead of x64 worked but no OpenCV applications can be ran. 
Couple of different errors appear:

```
'myOpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\LK\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\myOpenCV\Debug\myOpenCV.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'myOpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'myOpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'myOpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'myOpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\opencv246\build\x86\vc11\bin\opencv_core246d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'myOpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\opencv246\build\x86\vc11\bin\opencv_highgui246d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'myOpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp120d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'myOpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr120d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'myOpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\guard32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'myOpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'myOpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'myOpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'myOpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'myOpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'myOpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'myOpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'myOpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'myOpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'myOpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'myOpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'myOpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'myOpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\fltLib.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'myOpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntmarta.dll'. Symbols loaded.
The program '[4284] myOpenCV.exe' has exited with code -1073741515 (0xc0000135) 'A dependent dll was not found'.
```

Also a window appears saying the program cannot be executed because MSVCP110D.dll is missing. Should I install something? Or maybe just change the project settings?