# errors in dispaying image

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I am trying to display a image and this 3 errors are coming..

Error   1

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::imshow(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class cv::_InputArray const &)" (?imshow@cv@@YAXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV_InputArray@1@@Z) referenced in function _main    
C:\Users\jai guru umesh\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\test\test\
test.obj    
test
```

Error   2

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(class cv::Mat const &)" (??0_InputArray@cv@@QAE@ABVMat@1@@Z) referenced in function _main    
C:\Users\jai guru umesh\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\test\test\
test.obj    
test
```

Error   3

```
error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals   
C:\Users\jai guru umesh\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\test\Debug\test.exe
    1   
1
```

test

program

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    Mat image;
    image = imread("C:\\Users\\jai guru umesh\\Desktop\\6.jpg " ,0);
    // any other variables must also be declared here
    if( argc != 2) {
        cout <<" Usage: display_image ImageToLoadAndDisplay" << endl;
        return -1;
    }


    if(! image.data )                              // Check for invalid input
    {
        cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow( "Display window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );// Create a window for display.
   imshow("Display Window",image);            // Show our image inside it.

    waitKey(0);                                          // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have no idea of what `openvc2` is but probably is a library that needs to be linked to statically. If you have no idea of what I´m talking look at [this](http://www.steptools.com/support/stdev_docs/help/settings_vc10.html#link) example

Comment: did you linked opencv libraries from Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies?

Comment: @thomas I linked all the opencv libraries..If i am doing the same program in c format then it is working..

Comment: If OpenCV was installed/built as 64 bit library, make sure that you compile your project as 64-bit. Also, if you are compiling in Debug configuration, make sure that you link to debug version of OpenCV `.lib` files, and vice versa in case of the release version. See [this link for example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19590460/1121420)